# Maximum number of variables in an Equation of State - thermodynamics

Tags: thermodynamics

Recently during a discussion in basic thermodynamics, one of my friends queried saying why do we use only three state variables when defining an equation of state for a system $f(X,Y,T) = 0$, why not more than that ? (Of course, it depends on what the system is physically). I have been trying to answer this question but I have not found examples otherwise and not found a convincing reason as to why only three variables. **Are there systems with equation of state being described by more than three variables. If not, is there a reason to why the number of variables is only three ?**

Comment: Well, in basic thermodynamics they try not to confuse you too much. Take an ideal gas - pretty straightforward.  Now, make each gas particle have a magnetic moment, and place the gas in a very tall tube in a strong oscillating magnetic field and large gravitational gradient.  Oops - just added more degrees of freedom (and lots of confusion). Once you have the basics, it becomes "easy" to add additional degrees of freedom as necessary.

Comment: @JonCuster : So in principle there is no restriction on the number of parameters, but for all practical reasons that we have in our physical world, its mostly three, right ?

Comment: You will need a state parameter for each separate contribution to the free energy. So, there are many times you would use additional variables, just not in intro thermodynamics courses.  Examples include: gravity, magnetic contributions, dielectric contributions, strain energy in a solid (distinct from P-V if it is shear), etc.